# add the export to file functionality in datatables

Tags: datatables

How do I add the export to file functionality in datatables described [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

here is my basic fiddle with 2 rows of test data
https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/

Am I correct to say that I should just add all the libraries js and css, and the following piece of code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I have done this in the below fiddle but it does not work.
https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/1/

Can anyone advise how i get the csv, pdf, copy...etc buttons to work?
The way I describe above is obviously too simple to get it to work.
Maybe my reading of the documentation is not the best.
Would really appreciate some advise on this matter.

Comment: If you actually initialised your table, i.e `#employee-grid` and not the nonexisting `#example`, then it works -> **https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/2/**

Comment: tks for pointing out the blatant obvious! maybe the reason I asked was because I was trying to combine in with server side processing which I was struggling with so have asked a [q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728639/datatables-how-to-combine-server-side-processing-code-with-file-export-code)