# datatables + how to combine server side processing code with File export code

Tags: datatables

This is a datatables example of adding buttons to export data to csv, pdf, excel.... [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/1/)

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

This is a datatables example of Server-side processing

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Now how do I combine the above code into one, so that i have a data tables that does server side processing and that  this is my attempt, but I am not sure where it is wrong, or if indeed I am close.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]       
    } );
} );
```

I have tried various permutations but I am still getting an error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`
Can anyone advise?

This is my real example I am working with

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"employee-grid-data2.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                error: function(){  // error handling
                    $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                    $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server -- startagain1-index2.php </th></tr></tbody>');
                    $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                }
            },
            "dom:" 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export all rows from Datatables using Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692618/how-to-export-all-rows-from-datatables-using-ajax)

Comment: don't think this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the sintax error, change your code in this line:

#### Incorrect:

```
"dom:" 'Bfrtip',
```

#### Correct:

```
"dom" : 'Bfrtip',
```

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/42/)

Comment: just notice that `show X entries` disappears when the buttons show in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/3/). the `show X entries` is still  present here

Comment: Its for your response data, check https://datatables.net/manual/server-side, for draw the info data `show X entries` you should return this format: `{   "draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 57,  "recordsFiltered": 57, "data": [.....]}`

Comment: do I have to play with these options `"lengthMenu" : [[25, 100, -1], [25, 100, "All"]],"pageLength" : 50,` I can see page length working but `show X entries` is not longer viewable

Comment: Ok, Its problem can be for Dom Postion of the table https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html, Please Show your response data

Comment: `{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":999,"recordsFiltered":999,"data":[["2015-10-06","717","290","16019540","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","$29 Plan"],...` this is my response data

Comment: Check your data, when remove processing, not problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/sxqeauaz/4/ , but when you processing and not found the url its produce an error and not renderize info

Comment: sorry? this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/5/) I can see the show entries as the add buttons is commented out, but if I comment them in the show entries can't be viewed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109739/discussion-between-cmedina-and-hattricknz).

Comment: from the chat: 
ok ok
In your code change the dom lime
line*
dom": 'Bfltip',
jsfiddle.net/cmedina/sxqeauaz/…
missing the letter "l" -- > l - Length changing
more information
datatables.net/examples/…